# How to launch a terminal with a function defined in the same script?

Tags: bash

Have a look at the script below. I want to run the function `fopen` when `urxvt` is launched. The only way I can do it now is to move `fopen` into a separate file and then call `urxvt -e sh -c "path_to_script"`. I don't want to have two separate files. I want to be able to launch `urxvt` with a function instead of a script name. How can I do that?

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# function that I want to run when terminal opens
fopen() {
    ls
}

# I want to be able to call `urxvt` with a function
# This doesn't work
urxvt -e fopen

# This works, but this requires me to move `fopen` to another file
urxvt -e sh -c "path_to_script"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the function has to get into another child process.

You can *serialize* the function using `declare -f` to the child process.

```
... bash -c "$(declare -f fopen); fopen"
```

You can *export* the function into the environment, which is shared with the child process.

```
expport -f fopen
... bash -c 'fopen'
```